# Does anyone know what plant is this [see picture below]?

Tags: identification

[image]

This plant is growing under our maple tree. Can someone help me identify what this is?

I can post some more close up shots of the leaves later this evening.

**EDIT:** Here's the picture of the shape of the leaf in that plant.

[image]

The plant is right underneath the maple tree which has its small leaves like these:

[image]

There are not many plants nearby. We planted some roses and ~10-15 feet away we have a rhododendron and some [St John's wort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypericum_perforatum).

Comment: Your profile says you're in Bellevue, Washington. Is your maple tree also in Bellevue, Washington? Can you give us an idea of the overall size of the plants as well as the size of the leaves. Thanks!

Comment: What other trees live nearby?

Comment: @NiallC. The plant in question is about a foot high. See close up photos of the leaves from that plant. And yes the tree is in Bellevue, WA.

Comment: @stormy: There's only one maple tree and couple of huge pine trees which are in my neighbor's house.

Comment: Top picture looks like HORSE CHESTNUT Aesculus hippocastanum. The second picture, maple...need to see buds, seeds.  Were any big trees chopped down before you moved in?  How long have you lived in this home?  If this is Horse Chestnut...I would definitely go to the trouble to try to propagate.  I'd wait for fall before digging up and transplanting into a pot.

Answer (score 1):

Looks very much like a *Aesculus hippocastanum* , as @stormy said, a [Horse Chestnut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesculus_hippocastanum). The other, a [Japanese maple tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_palmatum) *Acer palmatum*.

Comment: Need more scale and bark texture to decide the species of maple...could be Acer glabrum if I knew the scale of those leaves.

Comment: Leaves shape differ clearly from _Acer glabrum_, I have a couple of this Japanese maple in my garden. I can include some pics in case needed

Comment: No problem...just checked out a few pictures to refresh my memory...grins!

Comment: I had to check pics of the _Acer Glabrum_ to confirm, did not know the specific name of that maple you suggested. Cheers

Comment: Aesculus hippocastanum has 7 leaflets. This image shows 5 (currently) so also consider other Aesculus species such as x carnea, sylvatica, etc.

Comment: Good point @Brenn; now I am not sure it is, yet, it is possible for the _aesculus hippocastanum_ to have 5 leaflets. Do you know of any other besides _aesculus carnea_ and _sylvatica_ that can be related to the pic?

Comment: Yup, @trox, you're right. A. hippocastanum can indeed have 5 leaflets. I didn't know that. Other 5-leafleted species include A. glabra, A. pavia, A. californica, A. parviflora... I believe there are more. I think a flower will be required for a specific ID on this one.